# Want to create,update and retrieve data from SqLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

For **Create** table :

```
private static void createAllTables(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    database.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + IN_RIDE_DATA + " (" + USER_ID + " REAL NOT NULL" +"," + TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE + " REAL NOT NULL" + "" + ");");
}
```

for **Update** table, want to save only displacement so i update every time because i want to override the data.

```
public void insertTotalDisplacement(String userID, Double displacement) {
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID, userID); //User phone No used as a USER ID
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE, displacement);

       database.update(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA,contentValues, NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID+" = "+userID, new String [] {});


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For **Retrieving** data, I used several ways to do this but data not save in database and not retrieved from database.

```
    public Cursor getTotalDisplacementDistance() {
    Cursor cursor=null;
    try {
        String[] columns = new String[]{NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE};
       //  cursor = database.rawQuery(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        //choice = String.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE)));

        Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT "+NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE+" where "+NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID+" = " +1+ " from"+NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA,new String [] {});
        //Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT * from IN_RIDE_DATA",new String [] {});


        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: have look [Sqlite CRUD operation](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: yes but not working yet

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in `getTotalDisplacementDistance` method, you are using **two cursor variables**, one has query result and other is null, and you are processing the one with null value.

Update it accordingly,

```
public Cursor getTotalDisplacementDistance() {
    Cursor cursor=null;
    try {

        cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE + " from IN_RIDE_DATA  where " + NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID + " = ?", new String[] {"1"});

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Comment: change the line with: `database.rawQuery("SELECT " + NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE + " from IN_RIDE_DATA  where " + NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID + " = 1", null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + IN_RIDE_DATA;
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID))));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE))));            

        // Adding data to your list
        list.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
db.endTransaction();
```

Edit

> Use you model class for setting data

Comment: Error inserting userID=1 
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: IN_RIDE_DATA.body (code 1299)

error while insertTotalDisplacement

Comment: I guess your last arguemt in update method should be like this `new String[]{userID}`

Answer (score 0):

I change these things

For **Creating** Table

```
private static void createAllTables(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    //database.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + IN_RIDE_DATA + " (" + USER_ID  +"," + TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE  + "" + ");");

    database.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + IN_RIDE_DATA + " ("
            + TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE + " TEXT, "
            + USER_ID + " TEXT"+");");

}
```

For **Deleting** Table

```
public void deleteDriverLocData() {
    try {
        database.delete(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For **Inserting**

```
public void insertDisplacement(String id, String displacement) {
    try {
        deleteDriverLocData();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.USER_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE, displacement);
        database.insert(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, null, contentValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For retrieving the values:

```
public String getDisplacement() {
    try {
        String[] columns = new String[]{NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_DATA, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String totaldisplacement = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.TOTAL_DISPLACEMENT_DISTANCE));
        return totaldisplacement;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```